# How to write data on bluetooth device( BLE) using evothings libraries?

Tags: cordova, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins

I trying to communicate with the ble device using Evothings libraries.

I was checking [this example for reference](https://evothings.com/doc/examples/arduino-led-onoff-ble.html)
where i noticed that its passing Uint8array as parameter to write the characteristic on to device.

```
app.device && app.device.writeDataArray(new Uint8Array([1]));
```

Now value is 1 which will turn on the led of device its working

```
app.device && app.device.writeDataArray(new Uint8Array([0]));
```

above code turns off the Led of the device.

Now in one example i have that is turning on the ble device and its led.

```
app.device && app.device.writeDataArray(new Uint8Array([70,49,13]), '0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb');
```

so i am not able to figure it out that how its communicating with the device how to figure it out which number to pass in Uint8Array to communicate with the other service of the devices.

And evothings.ble plugin reference is [here](https://evothings.com/doc/lib-doc/module-cordova-plugin-ble.html)

Any help or guidance will be great.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the updated BLE plugin API in place of the outdated EasyBLE library (the linked example uses EasyBLE).

Here is a guide that can be helpful: https://evothings.com/doc/tutorials/evothings-ble-api-guide.html

And here is an example: https://github.com/evothings/cordova-ble/tree/master/examples/core-api/tisensortag

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not able to understand the Uint8Array, means i am note able to find the docs regarding how the values are passed in that array regarding how to write the values to ble devices.